# Port for forwarding DNS queries to OpenDNS

Tags: dns, domain, windows-firewall, opendns, firewalld

I'm trying to configure DNS forwarders in domain controllers to OpenDNS. DNS forwarders are configured but the requests are not getting redirected via OpenDNS. I've allowed TCP port 53 to openDNS IPs in the firewall settings. Is that the right port to get DNS forwarding working, or do I need to allow UDP port 53 and TCP 443 also?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Traditional DNS works over UDP port 53.  OpenDNS does support [DNS over HTTPS](https://support.opendns.com/hc/en-us/articles/360038086532-Using-DNS-over-HTTPS-DoH-with-OpenDNS) which would require you to open TCP port 443.  But which one you need will depend on how you've configured your forwarder to connect to the OpenDNS servers.